# In Flashpoint Paradox how was Thawn in the alternate universe?

Tags: dc, justice-league, flashpoint-paradox, dc-animated-movie-universe

How was Thawn in that alternate universe with Flash? If it was only The Flash who changed the past wouldn't Professor Zoom be different as well?

Comment: Something to do with the Speed Force maybe?

Comment: I had this exact question and came here to ask it.  At least I wasnt alone in thinking of this.

Answer (score 4):

*** Spoilers ***

To understand, you'd need to read the comic - the movie leaves quite a few things out. In the comic, Professor Zoom understood the very point you bring up... that if he went back in time and erased The Flash from existence, it would prevent his own existence as well. To get around that, he came up with something diabolical:

> Zoom went back in time and killed Barry's mom (he was the unknown assailant), then hatched an elaborate scheme that essentially provoked Barry into going back and saving her. The death of his mother is what drove Barry into criminal forensics, which is what led to him later becoming The Flash. By preventing the event, Barry became a paradox - like a bubble in time - and Zoom could then kill him without affecting his own timeline. Since both men were time travelers from the original timeline, they were both equally resistant to the changes.

If you liked the animated version, I highly recommend the original comic event (it's called FlashPoint) - there are numerous differences, and the comic version has a much richer story regarding the events of the alternate timeline.

Comment: I +1'd your answer.  I had the same question as the OP.  I saw the movie, didnt read the comic.  Your answer "explains" how he would have existed in a timeline without the Flash.  But something doesnt make sense to me...  Zoom wouldnt *know* going back in time to kill Flash's mom and Barry going to rescue her would lead to the destruction of the world.  Why would he think of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Thawn still existed because he was from the Flash's personal future. Since he has travelled back in time to be in the "Flashpoint paradox" events, he is from a different timeline altogether. That establishes the fact that he can time travel as well. So two time travellers remain the same despite the changes in the timeline. (This explanation would've made perfect sense in the Whoniverse though!).
See if this answer makes sense to you.